# Can't get this keyword to work within a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build a small wrapper library for the node redis module.

```
var redis  = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient();

module.exports = {

    /*
     * Time To Live
     *
     * Time in seconds the cache will remain in
     * memory.
     */
    ttl: 120,

    /*
     * Time To Refresh
     *
     * Time buffer in seconds when the cache should
     * be refreshed. On a cache check, if the ttl
     * is less than the ttr, the cache will be
     * refreshed.
     */
    ttr: 60,

    /*
     * Check Cache
     *
     * Middleware to check if the request is cached
     * before executing the full request.
     */
    check: function (req, res, next) {
        var key = req.url.slice(1, req.url.length).replace('/', ':');
        client.get(key, function (err, value) {
            if (value !== null) {
                res.send(value);
                client.ttl(key, function (err, ttl) {
                    if (ttl < this.ttr) {
                        return next();
                    }
                    return;
                });
            } else {
                return next();
            }
        })
    },

    /*
     * Set Cache
     *
     * Takes a key and a value and stores it in redis.
     * Also takes the full response object "res" and
     * handles sending the response if it has not
     * already been sent.
     */
    set: function (url, value, res) {
        var key = url.slice(1, url.length).replace('/', ':');
        client.set(key, value);
        client.expire(key, this.ttl);
        if (!res.headersSent) {
            res.send(value);
        }
        return;
    },

    /*
     * Keygen Cache
     *
     * Takes a urls substring and creates a keyname
     * in line with redis best practices
    */
    keygen: function (url) {
        var key = url.slice(0,1).replace('/', ':');
        console.log(key);
        return key;
    }

};
```

I can't figure out how to use the 'this' keyword properly. If I try to reference this.ttl or this.ttr or call this.keygen from another function within the module.exports object it always turns up undefined. What is a structure I should be using to enable referencing functions internal to the same object?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but i don't know of which post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested functions in your `check` function, so the `this`-keyword relates to the inner function context and not to your object.

**First solution:**

```
function (req, res, next) {
    var _this = this;
    var key = req.url.slice(1, req.url.length).replace('/', ':');
    client.get(key, function (err, value) {
        if (value !== null) {
            res.send(value);
            client.ttl(key, function (err, ttl) {
                if (ttl < _this.ttr) {
                    return next();
                }
                return;
            });
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    })
}
```

And if you are using the function as a callback function bind your object to the callback function like this:

```
// replace "yourModule" with the name of your module
var yourModule = require('./yourModule.js');

// an example for expressjs (use get, post ... or something else)
app.get('/some/url', yourModule.check.bind(yourModule));
```

---

**Second solution** (IMHO the better one):

Another solution is to **use local variables** in your module (these are only visible in your module -> and this is what you want).
This is way more easier:

```
/*
 * Time To Live
 *
 * Time in seconds the cache will remain in
 * memory.
 */
var ttl = 120;

/*
 * Time To Refresh
 *
 * Time buffer in seconds when the cache should
 * be refreshed. On a cache check, if the ttl
 * is less than the ttr, the cache will be
 * refreshed.
 */
var ttr = 60;

/*
 * Check Cache
 *
 * Middleware to check if the request is cached
 * before executing the full request.
 */
var check = function (req, res, next) {
    var key = req.url.slice(1, req.url.length).replace('/', ':');
    client.get(key, function (err, value) {
        if (value !== null) {
            res.send(value);
            client.ttl(key, function (err, ttl) {
                if (ttl < ttr) {
                    return next();
                }
                return;
            });
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    })
};

/*
 * Set Cache
 *
 * Takes a key and a value and stores it in redis.
 * Also takes the full response object "res" and
 * handles sending the response if it has not
 * already been sent.
 */
var set = function (url, value, res) {
    var key = url.slice(1, url.length).replace('/', ':');
    client.set(key, value);
    client.expire(key, ttl);
    if (!res.headersSent) {
        res.send(value);
    }
    return;
};

/*
 * Keygen Cache
 *
 * Takes a urls substring and creates a keyname
 * in line with redis best practices
*/
var keygen = function (url) {
    var key = url.slice(0,1).replace('/', ':');
    console.log(key);
    return key;
};

/**
 * PUBLIC API
 */
module.exports = {
     check: check,
     set: set,
     keygen: keygen
};
```

Now because you are not relying on the context of the module you can simply do this:

```
// replace "yourModule" with the name of your module
var yourModule = require('./yourModule.js');

// an example for expressjs (use get, post ... or something else)
app.get('/some/url', yourModule.check);
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm still getting undefined with this strategy. If I put a console.log under the var _this = this; line and try to log _this.ttl I still get undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Nice catch. You're absolutely right. And that is working. Where can I learn more about where bind comes from and what it's doing and why I'm losing access to my object properties by using this as middleware?

Comment: I added a second solution. I think this is a good starting point to learn about javascript scope and the `this`-keyword: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Thank you. You have helped me immensely.

Comment: Third option use bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Very good answer but I will disagree on the 2nd option being better.  The code is slightly cleaner but it is a lot less configurable.  Since the local variables are in a closure you won't be able to configure the ttl or ttr.

Comment: @pllee You're right. But if OP wants to configure `ttl` or `ttr`, he can add setter to the public api (module.exports) object or adds the properties to the exports object directly and access these properties in the functions. I think it depends on the use case, so OP can choose what fits the best.